# Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

I have a custom module that hooks into a commerce extension module.

The function splits a payment for a product and splits it to beneficiaries who helped create the product.

I use user_referance module in a [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) field in the product content type to store the beneficiary users from the system. The drupal system log shows this when running through the function

```
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in      EntityAPIController->load() (line 219 of /www/opigno/profiles/opigno_lms/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.controller.inc).
```

Drupals error back trace function showed the error came from this line

```
  if (!empty($item_id)){
      $split_pay = commerce_funds_object_to_array(entity_load('field_collection_item',
array($item_id)));
  }
```

The function does run through fine but I'd like to squash any bugs that are appearing, the `$item_id` array only contains the `user_ids` of beneficiary users so i don't really understand why a non integer value is being passed

Comment: What exactly is in `$item_id`? It should be integer, or integer-compatible string, if you have something else there, you will have problems. Have you tried to `kpr($item_id)` before calling `entity_load`?

Comment: xdebug is showing this

$item_id = {array}[2]
0 = "12"
1 = "14"

Comment: So just don't wrap  `$item_id` into array. It already is an array. Use it directly, `entity_load('field_collection_item',
$item_id)`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, you just have to be sure it is an integer and not a string, also you can use entity_load_single:

```
if (!empty($item_id)){
$item_id = (int) $item_id;
  $split_pay = commerce_funds_object_to_array(entity_load_single('field_collection_item', $item_id));
}
```

Comment: Not worked for me

Comment: "entity_load_single" only works for ECK , though.

Answer (score 0):

If your `$item_id` is already array as you've mentioned:

> $item_id = {array}[2] 0 = "12" 1 = "14"

then you don't need to wrap it again into array.

Use it directly, like:

```
entity_load('field_collection_item', $item_id);
```

as per [@Mołot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127190/warning-array-flip-can-only-flip-string-and-integer-values#comment152044_127190) suggestion, or just make sure it's in the right expected format.

See: [`entity_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7.x) API:

> $ids: An array of entity IDs, or FALSE to load all entities.